# OnNewMessageCompose not called for Outlook Add-ins

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I was working on an Outlook Add-ins to insert a signature (based on a comunity sample). All of the sudden, it stops working on my computer. From what I can see, the function defined in the manifest is never called when a new message is composed. In fact, the function is called in Outlook web, but it isn't anymore for Outlook desktop  (Version 2202 Build 16.0.14931.20128) 64 bits. For most users, everything works well, but for some users, it doesn't work all the time.

Here is the definition in the manifest.xml

```
     <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="LaunchEvent">
       <LaunchEvents>
         <LaunchEvent Type="OnNewMessageCompose" FunctionName="checkSignature" />
         <LaunchEvent Type="OnNewAppointmentOrganizer" FunctionName="checkSignature" />
       </LaunchEvents>
       <SourceLocation resid="Autorun" />
     </ExtensionPoint>
      ...
    <bt:Urls>
      <bt:Url id="Autorun" DefaultValue="https://myurl.com/something/autorunweb.html"</bt:Url>
    </bt:Urls>
```

Can you tell me why this "checkSignature()" function is never called?

Or do you have any clue on how to debug this? I can't open DevTools until I open the Add-ins pane, but it is too late to check the action code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This might be a bug we are actively working on where the sandbox process experiences crashes for certain users, resulting in a failure to launch the add-in. Are you seeing an error infobar with the message "We're sorry, we couldn't access [add-in name]. Make sure you have a network connection. If the problem continues, please try again later"?

Comment: To debug  event-based add-ins see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/debug-autolaunch

Answer (score 0):

You can find the [Debug your event-based Outlook add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/debug-autolaunch) page in MSDN which describes how to debug event-based activation in your add-in. You have several options for creating your add-in project. Depending on the option you're using, the steps may vary.